# O que é "PostBack"?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp

Pode parecer uma pergunta boba, mas eu não consigo compreender como funciona uma postback, se alguém me conseguir explicar agradeço!

Comment: Dê uma olhada [neste link](https://www.devmedia.com.br/desvendando-asp-net-postback/29197) é uma boa leitura e ajuda a entender bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostBack é quando você faz uma requisição POST para a mesma pagina, ai ela recarrega e com os dados que você enviou ela se modifica.

Exemplo: Você possui uma pagina chamada Login.php ou Login.jsp, quando o usuário entrar pela primeira vez ira ter o campo para ele digitar o email e senha, assim que ele clicar no botão de "Entrar" você ira fazer post para a mesma pagina o Login.php, se o usuário e a senha forem validos ele ser redirecionado para a pagina de entrada por exemplo, caso não forem validos ele ira exibir uma mensagem de erro, ou seja a pagina faz uma requisição para ela mesma.

Comment: Opa, essa foi uma explicação breve e eu consegui compreender, obrigado!